# Making Subscribe to wait in Angular 4 for Subject

Tags: angular, rxjs, observable, angular2-observables, subject-observer

I have a text field in my HTML which calls back-end service in real time based on text entered. If a user enters something like 'abc', my service returns an object array which has this 'abc' name.

I am using Observable and Subject for this and I am returning processed service in my component. Please see the code.

**HTML Code**

```html
<input size="30" type="text" (keyup)="searchTerm$.next($event.target.value)">
```

**Component Code**

```
import { Subject } from 'rxjs/Subject';

searchString$ = new Subject<string>();

constructor() {

    this.searchString$.debounceTime(500)
    .distinctUntilChanged()
      .map(searchText => {
        return this.backEndService.fetchSearchStringData(searchText);
      })
      .subscribe(result => {
        console.log('result');
        console.log(JSON.stringify(result));

      });
}
```

When I I type 'abc' then it calls this **fetchSearchStringData** method. The service call is nothing but simple restService.post call and then setting the object is observable. Using that data to filter something and returning the finalized array.

But my component .subscribe us getting called first and only one time and it shows undefined value. (Where I am consoled.logging 'result').

How do I make sure I get the data once it gets a return from service in my subscribe of the component?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I cannot be sure unless you post code on how you make the `fetchSearchStringData` call. But inside you need to return a Promise or Observable. It looks like you're not returning anything, thus `consolte.log` prints `undefined`.

Then you can use `switchMap` to unwrap the result into the stream.

```
this.searchString$.debounceTime(500)
  .distinctUntilChanged()
  .switchMap(searchText => {
    return this.backEndService.fetchSearchStringData(searchText);
  })
  .subscribe(result => {
    console.log('result');
    console.log(JSON.stringify(result));
  });
```

Comment: After trying this swithcMap(), flow is going to Service but now it is not coming here in subscribe. that means it is not printing console.log(result) here. I think it is stuck in service somehow after using switchMap

Comment: There's probably something wrong with the `fetchSearchStringData` function.

Comment: using SwitchMap worked. Yes I was not returning .map response from service to this component and it worked smoothly.